Android Compose Webview not accessible with bluetooth keyboard
I have a compose which has a Scaffold with top bar having two icons, bottom bar having for tabs and in between a webview.
Now I cannot access the webview with bluetooth keyboard with dpad, and if I remove bottom tabs the webview is accessible.
please help.
